# How to prove a function has no real solutions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

So I have the equation:
$$
0.7=0.04(10+x)+\frac{2100}{(10+x)^3}
$$

And I have tried solving for x and have not succeeded, I believe it only has complex solutions.

So my question is, how do I go about actually proving this equation has no solutions for $x \ \varepsilon\ R$

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If you multiply with $(10+x)^3$, you get a polynomial of degree 4. As complex roots come in pairs (conjugate), it is well possible that there are 4 complex roots.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function $f(x)=0.04(10+x)+\frac{2100}{(10+x)^3}-0.7$.
If the equation has a real solution, then this function intersects the x axis at some point. It's a pretty "nice" function (continuous and differentiable at almost any point) which means you can use its derivatives and limits at specific points in order to practically know anything about its graph. Mainly - whether or not it intersects the x axis.

Comment: @Maam. Not only that ! I wrote $3\times 0.7=0.21$ !! Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=x+10$ you are looking for (non-zero) roots of $\ 0.04 y^4-0.7 y^3 +2100$, a quartic polynomial that grows beyond all bounds for large positive and negative values of $y$ and must have a minimum somewhere in-between.

At that minimum the first derivative of the expression, $0.16y^3-2.1y^2=(0.16y-2.1)y^2$, must be zero, but for both candidates, $y=0$ and $y=\frac{105}8$, the value of the expression is positive.

Answer (score -1):

Multiplying by $$100(10+x)^3$$ and simplifying we get

$$2\,{x}^{4}+45\,{x}^{3}+150\,{x}^{2}-2500\,x+90000=0$$
This equation has only complex Solutions.